# Como usar o mesmo BD SQLlite com java e cordova?

Tags: android, apache-cordova

Eu posso usar o mesmo BD usando Java e Cordova?
Ex: acessar os dados com cordova em um BD criado em java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, você pode acessar o arquivo do database do Cordova por meio de Java nativo do Android, para isso você deve entender que o Cordova utiliza uma versão do [W3C Web SQL Database](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/), que basicamente é uma implementação para Webkit, vale lembrar que o Cordova implementa um database caso o aparelho não apresente tal funcionalidade.

Bem, sabendo disso você pode acessar o database por meio do Java nativo para Android para isso basta implementar uma forma de ler o arquivo do Web SQL.
Ele fica localizado em

```
/data/data/{package name}/app_database/file__0/0000000000000001.db
```

Faça alguns testes para ter certeza que o arquivo se encontra no lugar certo.

Para implementar uma forma de abrir o banco de dados Web SQL  recomendo que leia as especificações no W3C clicando neste [link](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/) ou procure pelo plugin nativo do Cordova para lidar com Web SQL DB.